# Angular ngModel.$validate() is undefined in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to integrate a simple password validation check using angular.
From some reason no matter what I do ngModel.$validate() is not defined, and thus no validation actually occurs. Any help is greatly appericated. 
I've got a custom controller:

```
angular.module('todo')
    .controller('RegisterController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location) {
        $scope.register = function () {
    });
```

I've got a router:

```
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/todo', {
            templateUrl: './partials/todo.html',
            controller: 'TodoController'
        }).
        when('/register', {
            templateUrl: './partials/register.html',
            controller: 'RegisterController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/todo'
        });
});
```

And I've got a directive:

```
var compareTo = function() {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: {
            otherModelValue: "=compareTo"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$validators.compareTo = function(modelValue) {
                return modelValue == scope.otherModelValue;
            };

            scope.$watch("otherModelValue", function() {
                console.log('in otherModelValue ');
                console.log('ngModel.$validate() : ' + ngModel.$validate());
                ngModel.$validate();
            });
        }
    };
};
angular.module('todo').directive("compareTo", compareTo);
```

I bind it all together in the following manner:

```
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" required/> <br/>
    <input id="passwordConfirm" type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password"  ng-model="confirmPassword" required compare-to="password" /> <br/>
```

Comment: I believe/guess that you were actually reporting that ngModel.$validate - the function, not it's return value - was undefined.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: How did you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`ngModel.$validate()` should be undefined by design, because it doesn't return any specific value. Are you sure your validation isn't working, but has no way of displaying that validation? Try adding to your template (assuming your form has `name="form"`):

`<span ng-show="form.confirmPassword.$error.compareTo">Passwords must match</span>`

Also add a `name` attribute of `confirmPassword` to the confirmPassword field